# 404 image is missing on the meta site Page Not Found page

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, 404-page

The **404 image** is missing in the meta site's **Page Not Found** page.

The main sites' Page Not Found page has that image:

[codegolf.stackexchange.com/404](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/404)

But in the meta site it is missing:

[codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/404](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/404)

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: 404 image missing]

The meta site's image source is point to this [CDN path](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/skins/sketchymeta/img/sketchy-404.png), that is not available, where the main site's image source [CDN path](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/beta/img/404.png) is valid one.

Comment: +1 for the meta meta irony.